# How to extract html tags and attributes using java & regex?

Tags: java, html, regex

I have html document I want to read it using java code and print each tag with attributes.

How I can do that using regex?

Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of libraries around to parse HTML. Use one of them and do not try to do it with your own regexp.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Regex is not powerful enough to parse HTML documents. You will need an HTML parser. I suggest you look at [validator.nu](https://about.validator.nu/).